# .XML File Not Found Although It Is Exist

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio, windows-services

I've tried my best in searching to solve this issue, but nothing helps.
I have built Windows Service app. In debug mode everything works perfectly and has no issue in reading and use `haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml`, but once I publish the service an exception is thrown on logs file I had created, exception MSG:

> File 'haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml' not found

Although it exists. I have tried many solutions such as change the -Output Directory options as well as -Build Action properties that are related with this .xml file but nothing happened and issue still.

The attached image shows the published service which includes the .xml file.

[image]

Comment: "although it is exist" - in the current directory of the process? Don't forget that that's the directory that any relative filenames will be resolved against... (Try logging `Environment.CurrentDirectory` - I suspect it's not what you expect it to be.)

Comment: You need to add the xml to project.  From Solution Explorer, right click parent of where the cs files are located.  Then select ADD existing item and browse for xml in picture above.   Thn right click xml file and under properties select a copy method for Copy To output Directory.  Somebody must of manually put the xml file in the debug folder and not the release folder.  Adding to project will automatically copy to both debug and release when the xml gets changed.